# Mapping lists with jaxb on resteasy with jettison json provider

Tags: json, jboss, jaxb, resteasy, jettison

I have a method

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Conversation> getMyConversations() { /* ... */ }
```

The json output is something like

```
[{"conversation" : { ... }}, {"conversation" : { ... }}]
```

However, I'd like to output this

```
"conversations" :  [{"conversation" : { ... }}, {"conversation" : { ... }}]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? If so it would be much appreciated if you shared the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is how JBoss RestEasy is designed to behave: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#json_list

I've seen this worked around by returning the list as a member of another class, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ConversationSet")
public class ConversationSet {
    private Set<Conversation> sonversations;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

This will produce something like the following:

```
   {
     "conversationSet": 
     {
       "conversations" :  [{"conversation" : { ... }}, {"conversation" : { ... }}]
     }
   }
```

which is closer to what most clients expect for JSON.